# What should I do about a question I asked, which I now realize is a bad question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, deletion

I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311708/can-we-modify-etcs-to-handle-structures-directly-as-objects-in-their-own-right) the other day because it seemed like a good idea at the time. However, I now realize it was an incredibly stupid question!

What's good etiquette in situations like this? Deletion? Should I just leave it alone???

Answer (score 10):

Since the question has a number of upvoted answers, it seems to have generated some good responses. It sounds to me as if the question has merit, if only to elicit good answers. These answers may be useful to some other user who might ask the same question.

In any case, since the question has upvoted answers, there is not much you can do. You cannot delete the question without moderator intervention, and without extenuating circumstances, a moderator won't delete what appears to be good content.